# User.IsInRole always returning true ASP.NET IDENTITY

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I'm trying a basic customization of my _layourpartial file by returning a list item for only users within admin role

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
    @if (User.IsInRole("admin"))
    {
        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Dashboard", "Dashboard", "Home")</li>
    }
    <li>
        @Html.ActionLink("Hello " + User.Identity.GetUserName() + "!", "Manage", "Account", routeValues: null, htmlAttributes: new { title = "Manage" })
    </li>

</ul>
```

The problem is that when i delete a user from admin role , User.IsInRole still returns true.

I tried to delete cookies, logout/login, restart iis express ,...

Nothing works!

Comment: What about in the DB? Have you actually deleted the role?

Comment: Did you check that delete user-role is saved in the DB?

Comment: I deleted the user from role using usermanager.removefromrole(),the row associating user to role get removed from db and it doesnt work still user.isuserinrole returns true, i tried to remove the row direclty from db, still nothing. Now i removed the role completely and it doesn't work ... I checked IsUserInRole overview it's a runtime method so I'm pretty sure that some data is stored somewhere but don't know where

Comment: This is brilliant. Who's idea is an IsInRole method that doesn't actually check whether a user is currently in that role?

Answer (score 2):

In Identity current users roles store as claims and `User.IsInRole()` checks applied claims not actual roles. To remove a role from current users claims do following:

```
var identity = (User.Identity as ClaimsIdentity);
var adminClaim = identity.Claims.FirstOrDefault(c => c.Type == ClaimTypes.Role && c.Value == "admin");
if(adminClaim!=null)
    identity.RemoveClaim(adminClaim);
```

Or you could check actual roles of current user instead of assigned claims by following code:

```
HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext()
    .GetUserManager<ApplicationUserManager>()
    .IsInRole(User.Identity.GetUserId(), "admin");
```

Comment: are you sure about that ?
First, from where you got the GetUserManager ?
Then, I want to check if a user is an admin in the view  not controller.
Moreover, i don't find any claim? where is it stored ?

Comment: Add `@using  Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Owin` in beginning of your view `GetUserManager()` is a extension method. Don't defer where you want check rule is same. When user signed in claims are generated and stored in session. But my answer based on **Identity** as you said you are using in the project.

Comment: So shouldn't the method be named, HasRoleClaim() or something like that?